# Reading CSV line-by-line into multiple text boxes in C#

Tags: c#, csv, textbox, textfieldparser

I am looking to read a CSV into multiple text boxes in a form.  Each line of the CSV file has a different number of columns and I need it to read each line of the CSV separately - I don't want the blank values at the end of the row to be written in to textboxes.  The CSV looks like this:

```
M,7,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,300,0.07
f,,0,f,0,395,1,f,t,f,,,,,,
DATA/BMP99_15.BIN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,5,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
12,1,1,ATM,,,,,,,,,,,,
0.0315,0,180,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
1,2,181,0,,,,,,,,,,,,
47.5,352,0,0,12,180,0,0,,,,,,,,
250,2215,15,30,T,N,W,1,A,A,,,,,,
```

All it has to do is on a button click, read each line of the comma separated values and put each of the values into textboxes in sequential order.  i.e. textbox1 = CSV value 1, textbox2 = CSV value 2, and so on.

The form looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJHm7.png), with each row corresponding a row in the CSV.

This is what I currently have, I've never worked with textfield parser so it was more just a test to see if I could actually get it to write a single text box.

```
    private void buttonreadcsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Filepath\inputtest1.csv");
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            tbmodel.Text = fields[0];
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Maybe you should post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

With simple `File` read and `string.Split` you can read a csv file, and get all fields per line. To ignore empty entries, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

**Edit**
Added a workaround helper method `RemoveEmptyEntriesAtEnd` which removes empty strings (null, empty, white-space) at end of a string array!

```
var rows = File.ReadAllLines("C:\YourDirectory\data.csv"); //get all rows/lines
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    //string[] fields = RemoveEmptyEntriesAtEnd(row.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    string[] fields = RemoveEmptyEntriesAtEnd(row.Split(','));
    tbmodel.Text = fields[0]; //and other models.....
    tbmodelN.Text = fields.Length > N ? fields[N] : string.Empty; //when using N-th index of field
}

//The helper method
public static string[] RemoveEmptyEntriesAtEnd(string[] strArray)
{
    var arrRev = strArray.Reverse();
    var emptyEntriesAtEnd = 0;
    foreach (var item in arrRev)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            emptyEntriesAtEnd++;
        else
            break;
    }
    return arrRev.Skip(emptyEntriesAtEnd).Reverse().ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I would be concerned that `RemoveEmptyEntries` would cause blank values to shift, like those in row 4 of his sample data

Comment: @Hambone true! I have updated the answer with a workaround.

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' when I try to fill in other text boxes.  For instance, I have tb1.Text = fields[0]; tb2.Text = fields[1]; tb3.Text = fields[2].  Is that the correct way to fill in each text box?

Comment: because we are removing empty entries at end, the size of resulting array will reduce, hence the exception. See the update on how to safely use the index. `tbmodelN.Text = fields.Length > N ? fields[N] : string.Empty;`